# Get image URL from google places web API (nearby search)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

when I run the following HTTP request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=[API KEY]&location=${lat},${lng}&radius=400
```

..i get a response which is an array of objects (places)...each object has a key called photos (which is also an array of objects).  I dont see a "getURL" method, so how do I get the image URL for the place?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Places API web service returns array of photos in the response. Each element in this array has a `photo_reference` field. So you can use the photo reference to get a photo using the following URL:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photoreference=YOUR_PHOTO_REFERENCE&maxwidth=600&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

For further details have a look at the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks....now how do you get the image URL from the response back from the "places photos"?  Documentation says it returns an "image" but does not specify how to get the URL

Comment: Although the API doesn't explain this, it is actually returning a redirect which will have a location header that has the actual public image URL in it.